# Displaying data retrieved from database as table headers

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having difficulty with displaying my database which I retrieved from database as column headers. Here is my code which works perfect, but the only problem is that it displays my data in rows whereas I want it to be displayed as column header.

```
<?php 
  require('db.php');
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM new_emp");
  $stmt -> execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
  echo "<thead>";
  echo "<td>".$row['emp_name']."</td>";
  echo "<thead>";
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: you should replace `<td>` (table data) with `<tr>` (table row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `<tr>` for `Table row`.
Use `<th>` for `Table Header` Or `<td>` for `Table data`.

```
<?php 
  require('db.php');
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM new_emp");
  $stmt -> execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
  echo "<thead>";
  echo "<tr><th>".$row['emp_name']."</th></tr>";
  echo "<thead>";
  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
require('db.php');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM new_emp");
$stmt -> execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo "<thead><tr>";  
foreach ($result as $row) {
 foreach($row as $c)
   echo "<th>".$c."</th>";
}
echo "</tr></thead>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing  with  will solve your purpose.But the code you have written will add multiple table headers. It's fine if that is your requirement. Otherwise you need to change your code as below.

```
<?php 
require('db.php');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM new_emp");
$stmt -> execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo "<thead><tr>";
foreach ($result as $row) {
echo "<th>".$row['emp_name']."</th></tr>";
}
echo "</th></thead>";
?>
```